# Отправка JSON данных через vue.js

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js

Есть одна функция. Я получаю JSON с локалхоста на /receive/ , вывожу данные на страницу при помощи vue.js

Такая конструкция работает, данные в браузере выводятся:

```
fetch('/receive/')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(cards => 
    new Vue({
        el: '#cards',
        data: {cards}
    })
)
```

Однако, мне не нравится, что Vue функция находится внутри основной. нужно, чтобы она была отделена, и данные в нее передавались. Но никак не могу понять, как ее переписать. Пробовал так, но не выходит...

Неправильный вариант:

```
var container = new Vue({
    el: '#cards',
    data: {cards}
})

fetch('/receive/')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(cards => container.data)
```

Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` в `fetch` свой, сохраняем `this` до вызова `fetch`.

```js
var container = new Vue({
  el: '#cards',
  data: function() {
    return {
      cards: 'no cards'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getCards();

  },
  methods: {
    getCards() {
      let that = this; // The real this
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(json) {
          that.cards = json.title;

        });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.runtime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="cards"> {{cards}}</div>
```

Comment: _«this в fetch свой»_ - в стрелочной функции? Серьезно?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете изменять свойства объекта Vue когда угодно и где угодно, но не выносите логику из объекта.
Например, вот так можно загрузить данные "карточек" при создании, в хуке жизненного цикла `created`:

```js
var container = new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
    src: 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5afbf3e60fb4d74cdf23de08/1', 
    cards: ['Loading...']
  }, 
  created: function () {
    fetch(this.src).then(r => r.json()).then(obj => this.cards = obj.cards);
  }
});
```

```css
body { background-color: #eee7; }

[v-cloak] { visibility: hidden; }

.card-block {
  width: 300px; margin: 16px auto; padding: 16px; 
  text-align: center; font: 300 30px sans-serif; 
  background-color: #fff; box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 #0002;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" v-cloak>
  <div class="card-block" v-for="card in cards">{{card}}</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

Если требуется реактивная подгрузка асинхронно обновляемых данных, реализуйте в объекте Vue метод, и:

- просто вызывайте его, когда нет зависимостей от других свойств в `data`;
- в случае зависимостей, например, когда юзер меняет источник данных и нужно сформировать URL - используйте `watch` (чтобы вызывать метод обновления при изменении).

Не помещайте асинхронный код в функции `computed` свойств - это не будет работать, так как работать не должно: значение свойства возвращается синхронно.

---

Более подробная информация содержится [в документации Vue](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/).

Answer (score 1):

Что вы пытались сделать строчкой `cards => container.data`? Возможно, вы таким образом пытались "затолкнуть" cards внутрь container.data - но на самом деле вы игнорируете параметр и возвращаете container.data.

Чтобы объект изменился - нужно использовать оператор присваивания:

```
.then(cards => container.cards = cards)
```

Еще одна ошибка - при инициализации. Переменной cards у вас не существует, а значит и использовать ее невозможно. Нужно использовать полный синтаксис и адекватное начальное значение:

```
var container = new Vue({
    el: '#cards',
    data: { cards: [] }
})
```